# C function to print the alphabet using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, runtime-error, alphabet

I have this code:

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for( p ; p < p + len ; p++ )
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char* abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printArray(abc, 26);
    return 0;
 }
```

That is suppose to print all the English alphabet letters, but there is a run-time error and I need to find why it is caused and how to fix it. 
I have tried anything that came up to my mind to fix it but nothing helped, it just prints a lot of random stuff. 
Thanks for the help in advance.
P.S: This is not a code I wrote, I just need to find the mistake and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition to stop

```
p < p + len
```

will not be false as you do `p++` in every iteration of the loop. You eventually access invalid memory locations and this causes Undefined Behavior and This what is causing the runtime-error. To fix it, use another variable

```
char *tmp=p+len;
```

and change the condition to

```
p < tmp
```

An alternative way would be to decrement `len` in each iteration. Exit the loop once `len` is zero:

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for( p ; len ; --len )
    {
        printf("%c", (*p)++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `p + len` is evaluated for each loop iteration, using the incremented value of `p` each time. This makes the loop go beyond the bounds of the array, triggering undefined behaviour.

You need to pre-calculate the one past the end point outside of the loop

```
char* end = p + len;

for( p ; p < end ; p++ )
{
    printf("%c", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for( p ; p < p + len ; p++ )
```

`p < p + len` is always true.

You need something like:

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    char *end = p + len; /* sum before the for loop */

    for( p ; p < end ; p++ )
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

But you don't need to pass the length, just iterate until you find the trailing `\0`, and if you are not going to modify the passed string, use `const char *`:

```
void printArray(const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        printf("%c", *p++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```